# Is it possible to avoid certain extended permissions as being "Required" and enable the 'Remove' link in the 'Application Settings' page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I enabled two new features in one of my applications. One of these features require only the 'email' permission and the other requires only 'friends_birthday'.

*I obviously use some PHP code (via the FB Graph API) to check if the user has already enabled the permission before I show a link or dialog with information regarding the new feature. So no, I do not request these specific permissions during the "login" process.*

This is an example of the code I use to request a permission using Facebook's JS SDK:

```
function requestPerm(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'permissions.request',
        display: 'iframe',//FYI: popup is forced for this permission
        perms: 'friends_birthday'
    },function(response){
        if(response && response.perms){
            enable_FriendBdayFeature();//load new content via AJAX
        }else{// if(!response.perms){
            skip_FriendBdayFeature();//hide link/msg
        }
    });
}
```

This is exactly the same way I request the "publish_stream" permission, which does in fact have the "Remove" link in the Application Settings page.

So the short question would be: Is it possible to enable the "Remove" link for specific extended permissions?

[image: Example of the permissions for one specific application (email, and friends_birthday were requested as mentioned)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions which are marked as 'required' in your example are data permissions.
It doesn't make sense for these to be optional as you should already only be asking for those permissions your application expressly requires to operate - allowing the user to opt-out of those would then cause your application to work incorrectly (i.e if you don't need a certain piece of information, don't ask for it).

The other permissions are 'extended' permissions which by their nature shouldn't be needed for most use-cases (e.g presence information or ability to post to the user's wall without using Facebook's SDK-supplied dialogs)

Comment: It makes perfectly sense yes. But I think many might also understand why I think Facebook should allow users to "remove" certain other permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically put, Facebook has confusingly made these prerequisites for the information you have requested. ie. If I ask someone `how old are you?` first I have to know `in reference to Jim`.

*See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)*

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but I still think Facebook should have enabled some way for developers to choose exactly which permissions should be 100% required for their applications to function.